# Why does XCode warn me that a method in another class might not exist when it does?

Tags: iphone, xcode, warnings

This is more of an annoyance since the code works fine but maybe there's something here that I should be doing differently. At any rate, all my calls to methods in a class that's different from the caller are getting flagged as "No '-foo' method found" or "'ClassA' may not respond to '-bar'" by XCode. In reality the methods **do** exist and I've imported the associated header (that contains the method definition) so XCode should know what's going on. Ideas?

Comment: Can you give a (small) example of code that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when Xcode does not know about the method you are trying to call.

This can be due to a few reasons:

- There is no method declaration for that method (either in the header file, or earlier in the .m file.
- There is no method declaration for the method and the method is below the one you are trying to call it in.
- You are not importing a header file you need.

Comment: Well... I was doing all those things. But after tinkering around a bit I noticed that the header for the external class method that was being called had to be in the .m file and not the .h for some reason. This seems a bit odd since I don't see why it should matter (since the .m file pulls in its own header) but when I moved the reference to the header file to the .m file the compiler was happy again. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you didn't misspell the method name (or used the wrong case, wrong parameter list, wrong parameter order, wrong parameter types, etc.) in the header.  Make sure you really imported the header before the code producing the error.